# T-SQL Stored procedure with multiple if-else conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL server SP which moves the data from a temporary grid to the main grid. The main purpose of this proc is to implement the upload process to move data from the temporary grid and when moved to main grid delete the rows from the temp grid. Hope I have explained the requirement clearly.
I have done this so far, but I ended up getting few errors. Is my approach correct or am I deviating from the destination. Can someone please suggest a workaround fro this.

Thanks

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [hsip].[MDT] 
(
@cRegion CHAR(2) = '00',
@cState_Code CHAR(2) = '00',
@nFY NUMERIC(4,0) = 0,
@nREPORT_ID NUMERIC(2,0) = 0,
@nSECTION_ID NUMERIC(2,0) = 0,
@nSUBSECTION_ID NUMERIC(2,0) = 0,
@nDISPLAY_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
@nQUESTION_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
@nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
@sUSER_ID VARCHAR(25) = NULL,
@nIsMerge char ='N'
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @starting_row_index as integer=0,
            @ncolumn_index as integer=0,
            @sresponse_string as varchar(4000),
            @srepsonse_stringm as varchar(4000),
            @response_stringo as varchar(4000),
            @nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID as numeric(38,0),


  select qd.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID
from FY_ST_QUESTION_DETAIL qd inner join FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO qi
on qd.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID =  qi.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID
       where qi.region = @cRegion
         and qi.state_code = @cState_Code
         and qi.fy = @nFY
         and qi.report_id = @nREPORT_ID
         and qi.section_id = @nSECTION_ID
         and qi.subsection_id = @nSUBSECTION_ID
         and qi.display_number = @nDISPLAY_NUMBER
         and qi.QUESTION_NUMBER = @nQUESTION_NUMBER
         and ( QI.REPORTER_ID = @sUSER_ID or
               QI.DELEGATE_ID = @suser_id or
               QI.SUB_DELEGATE_ID = @suser_id )
         and QD.QUESTION_PART_NUMBER = @nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER;

         set @ncolumn_index=
         case
         when (@nREPORT_ID = 1 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 21) then  17
            when (@nREPORT_ID = 1 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 32) then  16
            when (@nREPORT_ID = 3 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 11) then  15
            when (@nREPORT_ID = 3 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 12) then  27
        end;

if(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID >0)

        if(@nIsMerge = 'Y')

        select (max(ad.ROW_NUMBER)) 
        from FY_ST_ANSWER_DETAIL as ad
        where ad.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID=@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID;

        else

        --begin

        delete from FY_ST_ANSWER_DETAIL ad
        where ad.fy_st_question_dtl_table_id = @nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID;

        end;

        INSERT INTO FY_ST_ANSWER_DETAIL AD
            SELECT UL.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID,UL.REGION,UL.STATE_CODE,UL.FY,
                   UL.REPORT_ID,UL.SECTION_ID,UL.SUBSECTION_ID,
                   UL.DISPLAY_NUMBER,UL.QUESTION_NUMBER,UL.QUESTION_PART_NUMBER,
                   UL.ROW_NUMBER+@starting_row_index,
                   UL.COLUMN_NUMBER,
                   UL.LAST_UPDATE_USERID,UL.LAST_UPDATE_TIME,
                   UL.RESPONSE_STRING
              FROM UPLOAD_TEMP_DATA UL
             WHERE UL.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID = @nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID
               and UL.COLUMN_NUMBER <= @ncolumn_index;

               DELETE FROM UPLOAD_TEMP_DATA UL
              WHERE UL.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID = @nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID;

--end;


END
GO
```

Comment: You might have a few mis-matched begin / ends.  I would format your code consistently so that you can identify this.  Also, you've said that you are getting errors, but not which errors.  As a general point, you might be able to split off some of your statements and test the independently.

Comment: I think you need to work on the "begin" and "end" logic.  When you have a condition statement it needs to immediately be followed by a Begin command.  If it does not it only executes the line that immediately follows the condition statement.'

Comment: Yes your Begin's and Ends are not right you need to uncomment the ones that are commented and add a BEGIN directly after your first if.  Then a begin and end around your if(@nISMerge='Y').  But what are you trying to do with this sp?  You are selecting a result set then doing one of the following selecting a second result set which will be a single row scalar value with no column alias. , deleting rows from a table, or inserting  rows and deleting others from another table. Just seems odd flow but I don't know your business case so all might be good.

Comment: also need to take out table alias on the delete statements or add them in front of from as well DELETE ad FROM asdfsf ad. And declare all of your variables you are using and more mess.....

Answer (score 2):

There's a dangling comma at the end of your declare in the stored proc. That's one of your error problems.

Comment: Finally fixed all the errors and query runs fine. Thanks all!!

Answer (score -1):

I did this and query ran fine:

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @starting_row_index as integer=0,
            @ncolumn_index as integer=0,
            @sresponse_string as varchar(4000),
            @srepsonse_stringm as varchar(4000),
            @response_stringo as varchar(4000),
            @nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID as numeric(38,0);


  select qd.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID
from FY_ST_QUESTION_DETAIL qd inner join FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO qi
on qd.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID =  qi.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID
       where qi.region = @cRegion
         and qi.state_code = @cState_Code
         and qi.fy = @nFY
         and qi.report_id = @nREPORT_ID
         and qi.section_id = @nSECTION_ID
         and qi.subsection_id = @nSUBSECTION_ID
         and qi.display_number = @nDISPLAY_NUMBER
         and qi.QUESTION_NUMBER = @nQUESTION_NUMBER
         and ( QI.REPORTER_ID = @sUSER_ID or
               QI.DELEGATE_ID = @suser_id or
               QI.SUB_DELEGATE_ID = @suser_id )
         and QD.QUESTION_PART_NUMBER = @nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER;

         set @ncolumn_index=
         case
         when (@nREPORT_ID = 1 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 21) then  17
            when (@nREPORT_ID = 1 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 32) then  16
            when (@nREPORT_ID = 3 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 11) then  15
            when (@nREPORT_ID = 3 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 12) then  27
        end;


if(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID >0)
begin
if( @nIsMerge = 'Y')
 Begin
    select (max(ad.ROW_NUMBER)) 
    from FY_ST_ANSWER_DETAIL as ad
    where ad.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID=@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID;

 end
else
begin

    delete ad from FY_ST_ANSWER_DETAIL ad
    where ad.fy_st_question_dtl_table_id = @nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID;
end

-- --if(@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID >0)
-- --begin

insert into FY_ST_ANSWER_DETAIL (FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, REGION, STATE_CODE, FY, REPORT_ID, SECTION_ID, SUBSECTION_ID,
 DISPLAY_NUMBER, QUESTION_NUMBER, QUESTION_PART_NUMBER, row_number, COLUMN_NUMBER, LAST_UPDATE_USERID, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, RESPONSE_STRING)

select FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, REGION, STATE_CODE, FY, REPORT_ID, SECTION_ID, SUBSECTION_ID, DISPLAY_NUMBER, QUESTION_NUMBER, QUESTION_PART_NUMBER, row_number, COLUMN_NUMBER, LAST_UPDATE_USERID, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, RESPONSE_STRING

 from upload_temp_data 

 where FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID = @nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID and 
 COLUMN_NUMBER <= @ncolumn_index;
end

else
begin
DELETE ul FROM UPLOAD_TEMP_DATA UL
WHERE UL.FY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID = @nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID;
end
```